# Verify Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86) version with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I manage an application that requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86) version 14.25.x or higher.  The server I'm testing on has version 14.34.31931 and I can find that in PowerShell with:

```
$Key = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x86,x86,14.34,bundle'

$Key.Version
```

I'm wondering, instead of having "VC,redist.x86,x86,14.34,bundle" in that last spot of the Get-ItemProperty, if I can search for something containing  "VC,redist.x86" and use that key, regardless of the version?  I know if I get that, I can compare the actual version number, but it seems with my current search, I can only search based on already knowing that it's version 14.34.x.

Comment: Sure, you can use `*` wildcards with the `-Path` parameter: `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x86,*' -Name Version`